# php fpassthru has an extra character at the start of the file

Tags: php

I would like to be able to down load a file using a php script
I am using the demo code from the man pages however my jpeg that is downloaded is corrupted.
I did a hex compare and found that the downloaded file has one extra 0 bit at the begging of the file. How can I fix this?

Comment: `fpassthru` does not add that. It originates elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Most probably you have a PHP notice/warning coming out or some kind of output that breaks the file. Try setting `error_reporting(0);` in the beginning of your code and see if there is any output code left in your script. :)

Comment: Also: be on the lookout for any whitespace or other characters outside your `<?php ?>` tags.  Consider omitting the final `?>` tag entirely, so that there cannot possibly be any undesired characters after it (this is allowed by PHP, and part of many PHP coding standards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that PHP is emitting some output before the JPEG file gets passed through.  This could be because of whitespace before the opening

One thing to watch for is a BOM in UTF8 files.  The BOM is unnecessary in UTF8, and can in fact lead to problems such as the one you're encountering, but some editors add it to UTF8 files anyway.  How to remove it depends on your editor.